# Is the function being called more than once?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to add the song title and artist to a database every time the song changes. The program currently does that, but for some reason when I go to the next song, the same song is added more than once in the database, i.e. Song 1 is added 6 times in parse. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
   func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    print("entered background")


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

    backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({ () -> Void in

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask!)
        self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    })


}



func getNowPlayingItem() {
    if  let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem  {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
        let artisttest = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
        if let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] {

            let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")
            let object = PFObject(className: "MasterSongs")



            let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                    self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)


                }


                if self.Parsearray.contains(title! as! String){
                    print("already in db")
                }else{


                 objectPointer["title"] = title
                    objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    objectPointer["artist"] = artist
                    objectPointer.saveInBackground()
                    //parseClass.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    objectPointer.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if success == false {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            print("Posted succesfully")
                        }
                    })

                }

            })




        }

            if(artisttest == nil){
                let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")


                let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                    for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                        self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

                    }


                    if self.Parsearray.contains(title! as! String){
                        print("already in db")
                    }else{
                        objectPointer["title"] = title
                        objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                        objectPointer["artist"] = "No artist found :("
                        objectPointer.saveInBackground()


                    }

                })





            }


        }




}
 func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)

}
```

Comment: My guess: You add each time the observer that will call `getNowPlayingItem`, but you don't remove it. So when `applicationDidBecomeActive:` remove the observer.

Comment: Haha, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that you add an observer for `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification` every time `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called.

You didn't include the `applicationDidEnterForeground` function - but hopefully you are removing those observer there.  If you don't remove the observers, it would cause the  `getNowPlayingItem` selector to be called for each `applicationDidEnterBackground`. So 6 `applicationDidEnterBackground` = 6 `getNowPlayingItem`.

Comment: I updated my code,but I'm still running into the same error.

Comment: It's being added multiple times even before I re open the app.